# Error creating key vault certificate in Azure CLI

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-cli

I am trying to add a certificate to an Azure Key Vault using Azure CLI. I'm following the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az_keyvault_certificate_create) and the quickstart [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/quick-create-cli). Both pages say the command to generate a certificate is:

`az keyvault certificate create --vault-name vaultname -n cert1 -p "$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy)"`

I have this exact line in my script:

`az keyvault certificate create --vault-name $keyVault -n $certName -p "$(az keyvault certificate get-default-policy)"`

I get the following exception every time I run it. Am I missing something obvious here?

`az : Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 5 (char 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because Powershell saves the output of `get-default-policy` in a different encoding from that of bash and CMD.

Please use this workaround:

```
az keyvault certificate get-default-policy | Out-File -Encoding utf8 defaultpolicy.json

az keyvault certificate create --vault-name $keyVault -n $certName --policy `@defaultpolicy.json
```